# What is the unique element which is used to identify desktop softwares?

Tags: windows, desktop, app-id

Just like there is an android app id for every android apps(com.microsoft.teams), what is the equivalent element for desktop software?

Answer (score 0):

You can get unique App Guid using following code:

```
String AppGuid = ((GuidAttribute)Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0]).Value;
```